# What is the best way to work with remote git repository based on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM (Debian 9) instance on Google Cloud Platform.

I've installed Apache on it, and want to serve my website. Now I want to find the best way to manage my source code there.

I've created a private git repository on GitHib, cloned it to some folder on my local machine (Windows) and to GCP VM `/var/www/html/` directory.

When I make changes in source code on my local machine I need to do:

1. Commit changes
2. Push from local machine to GitHub
3. Connect to VM via SSH
4. Pull from Github to VM

This way works quite good, but I need to connect to VM and pull every time when I want to update my website. As I do changes several times a day, is is not convenient for me...

Can I clone a repository directly from Compute Engine VM, so when I do commit+push, my changes will go live without any additional actions? If yes, how to do this? Would it be easier for me than my current method?

Or, maybe, there are some other ways to reach my goal?

I'm a beginner in all these technologies.

Comment: I see two possible approaches, both hard. First, you can setup a Github webhook listener at your server and connect the Github repository to the webhook. So every time you push to Github webhook sends a signal to your listener so the listener can pull.

Comment: A little bit simpler (for me, at least) is to have a bare repository at the server and a [push-to-deploy hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+deploy+hook) in it. You need to push to two repositories but that simpler for a novice than setting up a webhook. I usually use `post-update` hook, not `post-receive`.

Comment: @peter, thx for your answers, but maybe there is a way to do this without Github at all? I just dont know how to clone a repo from my GCP VM, and push changes directly to it...

Comment: You don't need to clone it 2nd time, you already have the repository. You only need to push to GCP VM.